# C-style arrays do not work with records anymore

Tags: java, arrays, java-15, java-16, java-record

I was previously using this contrived code

```
record Foo(int bar[]) {}
```

which is making use of the **C-style array**-notation. And it compiled fine in Java 15.

Now, all of the sudden, with the official release of **records** in Java 16, it does not compile anymore. Here is the output from **jshell**:

> ```java
> jshell> record Foo(int bar[]) {}
> |  Error:
> |  legacy array notation not allowed on record components
> |  record Foo(int bar[]) {}
> |                    ^
> ```

Why did it compile in Java 15, was this a bug? Out of curiousity, why is it not supported in records, while being supported anywhere else in Java?

I am using `javac` from [Adoptium](https://adoptium.net/) (based on OpenJDK).

Comment: Out of curiousity: *why* exactly were you using C-style array notations?

Comment: @MCEmperor Actually, a friend found this and I thought it would be great to share on SO.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Explanation

The C-style array notation is considered **legacy** and it seems that they are trying to fade it out when possible on new constructs (it can not be changed retrofitting on old constructs to not drop backwards compatibility).

You would have to ask an actual developer for the precise reasoning behind this decision.

---

### Bug

The fact that it worked in Java 15 is **indeed a bug**. The specifications actually did not allow it, even for Java 15, but this was overlooked and `javac` accidentally supported it.

They noticed it and fixed it for Java 16, hence it does not compile anymore.

You can read more about it here:

- Bug-report: [JDK-8250629](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8250629)
- Task to fix it: [JDK-8260739](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8260739)
- Actual commit: [rev/059df93c90a4](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/rev/059df93c90a4)

---

### JLS definition

The section in the JLS that does not allow the notation can be found at [JLS §8.10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.10.1), where it defines the syntax of `RecordComponent`s as:

```java
RecordComponent:
  {RecordComponentModifier} UnannType Identifier
  VariableArityRecordComponent
```

with

```java
VariableArityRecordComponent:
  {RecordComponentModifier} UnannType {Annotation} ... Identifier
```

and

```java
RecordComponentModifier:
  Annotation
```

Comment: Probably reused a snippet of parser definition from everywhere else before realizing they needed a copy-and-paste edit.

Comment: This explanation is accurate; the C-style array notation is considered legacy and is not being carried forward into new constructs.  We confronted this earlier when we did Local Variable Type Inference; C-style arrays would have complicated the feature for little benefit (e.g., `var x[] = ...`).  Trying to phase it out fully is likely more disruption than it is worth.

Comment: @BrianGoetz considering the millions of places in the JDK code itself, where this legacy syntax has been used, it would indeed be very disruptive. On the other hand, being forced to go through the code bears the chances to notice lots of the other WTFs in that code…